# Validator is not working on Resource routes in AdonisJS

Tags: validation, adonis.js

I'm having problems with validator on Route.resource(). The validator is not been applied and when I run the command "adonis route:list" the av:TrainingPlan and Workout validators are not being listed. You can see that my other validators are working on single endpoint verb like "Route.post" on /users, /sessions/ and /passwords. On app.js under start folder I checked that the register was made too and all validator was generated by adonis cli.

My routes file was made based on documentation:

```
Route.group(() => {
  Route.post('files', 'FileController.store')

  Route
    .resource('/training-plans', 'TrainingPlanController')
    .apiOnly()
    .validator(new Map([
      [['training-plans.store'], ['TrainingPlan']]
    ]))

  Route
    .resource('/workouts', 'WorkoutController')
    .apiOnly()
    .validator(new Map([
      [['workouts.store'], ['Workout']]
    ]))
}).middleware(['auth'])
```

TrainingPlan Validator:

```
'use strict'

class TrainingPlan {
  get validateAll () {
    return true
  }

  get rules () {
    return {
      title: 'required',
      description: 'required',
      start_date: `date|before:${new Date()}`,
      end_date: `date|before:${new Date()}`
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TrainingPlan
```

What I'm missing out?

[adonis route:list command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLWTs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved removing `/` before `/workouts` and `/training-plans` route.

I did not tested putting `/` before `workouts.store` and `training-plans.store` inside Map validator.